# Find unique combination of items from list A,B,C,D with highest sum of property X with the constraint of the sum of property Z doesn't exceed a value

Tags: linq, .net-core, constraints, constraint-programming

I have 4 lists (A,B,C,D) filled with the same type of object that looks something like this:

```
public class Class
{   
    public double X
    public double Z 
}
```

What I want to do is to pick out one item from each list, with the highest possible sum of X while the sum of Z does not exceed a set value.

The only solution I have figured out for myself is to brute force it by creating a list of all combinations and then extract from there.
This is might be a reasonable solution in my current case as A,B,C,D are all around 100 items each, so the number of items isn't insanely large.

But I am curious if and how this could be done "correctly" for a lower time complexity.

EDIT: Added example.

Lists with two items each.

```
A = [ 
      AItem1 = { X = 1, Z = 1 },
      AItem2 = { X = 2000, Z = 100} 
    ]
B = [ 
      BItem1 = { X = 200, Z = 20 },
      BItem2 ={ X = 2000, Z = 1} 
    ]
C = [ 
      CItem1 = { X = 1, Z = 1 }, 
      CItem2 = { X = 2000, Z = 1} 
    ]
D = [ 
      DItem1 = { X = 200, Z = 2 }, 
      DItem2 = { X = 1, Z = 1} 
    ]
```

Query: Find the combination of item with the highest sum of X with sum
of Z not exceeding 6.

Result: A list with the combination of items from query.

`[AItem1, BItem2, CItem2, DItem1]`

Comment: Could you add some example data please? Ie. input and the expected output.

Comment: @Riwen I have updated with a rudimentary example. Hope that helps explain my problem.

Answer (score 2):

In general, this is a type of [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) with the added restriction that at most four elements may be selected and that each element must be from a separate list of elements.

The standard type of algorithm for knapsack-style problems is to use dynamic programming (see more in the Wikpedia link above), which I think would work well for you case also. This will be pseudo-polynomial, but is often fast enough with some careful programming.

Another alternative would be to use a combinatorial solver of some kind (mixed integer programming, constraint programming, SAT, ...), but that is probably overkill for this problem. If there are more constraints and/or more choices on what is a good combination or solution, that may change.

Comment: Thank you! It is not an area I am at all familiar with, but I will read up on it and give it a go.